# proper use of onCompleted for GraphQL mutations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo

I want to run the query first. The query returns an id which is then required for the mutation. Currently, there's an issue with the order of how both things run from the `handleSubmit()`. If the mutation is successful, the console should print `console.log('Checking');`but that does not happen. The only output I get on the console is `What's the Id`and the value is probably something that was stored in one of my previous attempts. If the id was derived from this particular round of query, I would have seen `Working`on the log, but that doesn't happen either.

```
 const [loadUsers, { loading, data, error }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery, {
    variables: {
      where: { email: friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase() },
    },
    onCompleted: () => getFriendId(),
  });



  const [
    createUserRelationMutation,
    {
      data: addingFriendData,
      loading: addingFriendLoading,
      error: addingFriendError,
    },
  ] = useCreateUserRelationMutation({
    variables: {
      input: {
        relatedUserId: Number(id),
        type: RelationType.Friend,
        userId: 5,
      },
    },
    onCompleted: () => addFriend(),
  });
```

```
  const getFriendId = () => {
    console.log('Working');
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
        console.log('No user');
        setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
      } else {
        console.log('ID', data.users.nodes[0].id);
        setId(data.users.nodes[0].id);
      }
    } else {
      if (error) {
        setErrorMessage(error.message);
      }
    }
  };

  const addFriend = () => {
    console.log('Whats the Id', Number(id));
    if (addingFriendData) {
      console.log('Checking');
      console.log(addingFriendData);
    }
    if (addingFriendError) {
      console.log('errorFriend', addingFriendError.message);
      setErrorMessage(addingFriendError.message);
    }
  };

 const handleSubmit = () => {
    loadUsers();
    createUserRelationMutation();
  };
```

Before this, I was trying this:

```
const [id, setId] = useState('');
const [friendEmail, setFriendEmail] = useState('');

const [loadUsers, { loading, data, error }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery);
const [createUserRelationMutation, { data: addingFriendData, loading: addingFriendLoading, error: addingFriendError }] = useCreateUserRelationMutation();

const getFriendId = () => {
    console.log('Email', friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase());
    loadUsers({
      variables: {
        where: { email: friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase() },
      },
    });
    if (data) {     
        console.log('ID', data.users.nodes[0].id);
        setId(data.users.nodes[0].id);      
    } 
    addFriend();
  };

  const addFriend = () => {
    console.log('Whats the Id', Number(id));
       createUserRelationMutation({
        variables: {
               input: {relatedUserId: Number(id), type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 7 }
            },
       });
       if (addingFriendData){
         console.log('Checking')
         console.log(data);
       }
       if(addingFriendError){
         console.log('errorFriend', addingFriendError.message);
         setErrorMessage(addingFriendError.message);
       }
  }


const handleSubmit = () =>
    {getFriendId();};
```

However, in this case, the values of the `id` & other states weren't being updated timely. I was running a graphql query inside `getFriendId()`that returns an id, followed by a mutation (inside `addFriend()`, which uses the id, along with an input (email) that the user types in. The problem is that on the first attempt, the mutation works fine and with correct values. However, when I change the email address on the input and run the query/mutation again, the values from my previous attempt are being used.

In the second attempt, the mutation was still using the id that we got in the first attempt.

Edit:

```
onCompleted: (data) => getFriendId(data),

 const getFriendId = (data: any) => {
    console.log('Working');
    if (data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
        console.log('No user');
        setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
      } else {
        console.log('ID', data.users.nodes[0].id);
        setId(data.users.nodes[0].id);
      }
```

**Updated Code:**

```
 const [friendEmail, setFriendEmail] = useState('');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [loadUsers, { loading, data, error }] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery);

  const [
    createUserRelationMutation,
    {
      data: addingFriendData,
      loading: addingFriendLoading,
      error: addingFriendError,
    },
  ] = useCreateUserRelationMutation();


 const getFriendId = () => {
    console.log('Email', friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase());
    loadUsers({
      variables: {
        where: { email: friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase() },
      },
    });
    if (data) {
      if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
        console.log('No user');
        setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
      } else {
        console.log('ID', data.users.nodes[0].id);
        setId(data.users.nodes[0].id);
        addFriend(data.users.nodes[0].id); 

      }
    } else {
      console.log('No data');
      if (error) {
        setErrorMessage(error.message);
      }
    }
    //addFriend();
  };

  const addFriend = (idd: any) => {
    console.log('Whats the Id', Number(idd));
       createUserRelationMutation({
        variables: {
               input: {relatedUserId: Number(idd), type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 9 }
            },
       });
       if (addingFriendData){
         console.log('Checking')
         console.log(data);
       }
       if(addingFriendError){
         console.log('errorFriend', addingFriendError.message);
         setErrorMessage(addingFriendError.message);
       }
  }

    const handleSubmit = () =>
    {
    getFriendId();
    };
```

Comment: use `data` from `onCompleted` as parameter `onCompleted: (data) => add/getFriendId(data),` - why you're using NOT updated (yet) component scope `data` ? did you forgot what are functions params for?

Comment: @xadm It still doesn't fix the problem. I get the correct ```ID```and ```Working``` from the log of the ```getId()```but I don't get any output from the mutation ```addFriend``` which I am calling ```onCompleted``` of the ```createUserRelationMutation```

Comment: because using component scope (not updated) data - see my updated answer in earlier question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need state to store ID, instead pass the Id to addFriend method like show below

```
    const [friendEmail, setFriendEmail] = useState('');
    const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

    const _onLoadUserError = React.useCallback((error: ApolloError) => {
        setErrorMessage(error.message);
    }, []);

    const [
        createUserRelationMutation,
        {
            data: addingFriendData,
            loading: addingFriendLoading,
            error: addingFriendError,
            called: isMutationCalled
        },
    ] = useCreateUserRelationMutation();

    const addFriend = React.useCallback((idd: Number) => {
        console.log('Whats the Id', idd);
        createUserRelationMutation({
            variables: {
                input: { relatedUserId: idd, type: RelationType.Friend, userId: 9 }
            }
        });
    }, [createUserRelationMutation]);

    const getFriendId = React.useCallback((data: any) => {
        console.log('Email', friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase());
        if (data) {
            if (data.users.nodes.length == 0) {
                console.log('No user');
                setErrorMessage('User Not Found');
            } else {
                console.log('ID', data.users.nodes[0].id);
                addFriend(Number(data.users.nodes[0].id));

            }
        }
    }, [friendEmail, addFriend]);

    const [loadUsers] = useLazyQuery(LoadUsersQuery, {
        onCompleted: getFriendId,
        onError: _onLoadUserError
    });

    const handleSubmit = React.useCallback(() => {
        loadUsers({
            variables: {
                where: { email: friendEmail.toLocaleLowerCase() },
            }
        });
    }, [loadUsers, friendEmail]);

    if (!addingFriendLoading && isMutationCalled) {
        if (addingFriendData) {
            console.log('Checking')
            console.log(data);
        }
        if (addingFriendError) {
            console.log('errorFriend', addingFriendError.message);
            setErrorMessage(addingFriendError.message);
        }
    }
```

> **Update**

I have updated the above code, please refer to it. I'm assuming `useCreateUserRelationMutation` does not accept options as argument, if it accepts option then you could use onCompleted and onError just like `loadUsers` query.

Comment: I tried this but what happens is that when I click the button first time, I get two logs ```Email```and ```No data```. However, when I click on it for the second time, the query runs properly and I get ```Whats the Id```and ```ID```too. Still, there's no successful logs from the addFriend mutation. However, when I click on the button the third time, the mutation is also successful now. Why this unusual behavior?

Comment: This happens because you were not waiting for the mutation to complete (Mutations and queries are asynchronous), I have updated the above code, this might help you, please let me know if you face issues with this.

Comment: I get an error on ```onCompleted: getFriendId,``` that ```Block-scoped variable 'getFriendId' used before its declaration.```How can I fix this considering that hooks should be called at the top? I am using TS

Comment: I have updated the code by reordering the declarations, I hope this would fix the issue that you are facing.

Comment: The mutation and query seem to work. However, while I am erasing something from the text field, I keep seeing more 'Checking' logs. Later on I need to add checks to see if the mutation is successful or not. If yes, I have to show alerts. I was planning to do it in ```if (addingFriendData)``` but since that's always true, what can I do?

Comment: After trying with one email address, if I use another one, it works fine but if I hit the button with the same email input, the mutation doesn't happen again. Also, is there any way I can automatically reset the input field and saved email state every time the button is clicked the mutation process is over?

Comment: 1. Then you must accept mutation options in `useCreateUserRelationMutation` hook and use onCompleted callback to show alerts

Comment: 2. You could set the email and error state back to empty on handle submit after invoking query or use onCompleted callback to reset state, and also use debounce technique to avoid executing queries on every immediate change in text field this would also solve too many re-renders issue

Comment: Make sure your query doesn't fail if email is invalid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213023/discussion-between-a125-and-shashi-kumar).

Comment: Hi, I came across this problem but I am not sure if its because of the way I'm trying to handle errors or something else. Could you have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62245474/onerror-in-graphql-mutations

Comment: Yes, I’ll look into it